# Modify hashes in an array based on another array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have two arrays like this:

```
a = [{'one'=>1, 'two'=>2},{'uno'=>1, 'dos'=>2}]
b = ['english', 'spanish']
```

I need to add a key-value pair to each hash in `a` to get this:

```
a = [{'one'=>1, 'two'=>2, 'language'=>'english'},{'uno'=>1, 'dos'=>2, 'language'=>'spanish'}]
```

I attempted this:

```
(0..a.length).each {|c| a[c]['language']=b[c]}
```

and it does not work. With this:

```
a[1]['language']=b[1]
(0..a.length).each {|c| puts c}
```

an error is shown:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method '[]=' for nil:NilClass)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `each` iterator over your `Range` reaches the last element (i.e. `a.length`), you will attempt to access a nonexisting element of `a`.

In your example, `a.length` is `2`, so on the last iteration of your `each`, you will attempt to access `a[2]`, which doesn't exist. (`a` only contains 2 elements wich indices 0 and 1.) `a[2]` evaluates to `nil`, so you will now attempt to call `nil['language']=b[2]`, which is syntactic sugar for `nil.[]=('language', b[2])`, and since `nil` doesn't have a `[]=` method, you get a `NoMethodError`.

The immediate fix is to not iterate off the end of `a`, by using an exclusive `Range`:

```
(0...a.length).each {|c| a[c]['language'] = b[c] }
```

By the way, the code you posted:

```
(0..a.length).each {|c| puts c }
```

should *clearly* have shown you that you iterate till `2` instead of `1`.

That's only the immediate fix, however. The *real* fix is to simply never iterate over a datastructure manually. That's what iterators are for.

Something like this, where Ruby will keep track of the index for you:

```
a.each_with_index do |hsh, i| hsh['language'] = b[i] end
```

Or, without fiddling with indices at all:

```
a.zip(b.zip(['language'].cycle).map(&:reverse).map(&Array.method(:[])).map(&:to_h)).map {|x, y| x.merge!(y) }
```

[Note: this last one doesn't mutate the original `Array`s and `Hash`es unlike the other ones.]

Answer (score 1):

```
a.zip(b){|h, v| h["language"] = v}
a # => [
  #      {"one"=>1, "two"=>2, "language"=>"english"},
  #      {"uno"=>1, "dos"=>2, "language"=>"spanish"}
  #    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that your `(0..a.length)` is inclusive. `a.length = 2` so you want to modify it to be `0...a.length` which is exclusive.

On a side note, you could use `Array#each_with_index` like this so you don't have to worry about the length and so on.

```
a.each_with_index do |hash, index|
  hash['language'] =  b[index]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method you could use

```
 b.each_with_index.with_object(a) do |(lang,i),obj|
   obj[i]["language"] = lang
   obj
 end
 #=>[
     {"one"=>1, "two"=>2, "language"=>"english"}, 
     {"uno"=>1, "dos"=>2, "language"=>"spanish"}
    ]
```

What this does is creates an `Enumerator` for `b` with `[element,index]` then it calls `with_object` using `a` as the object. It then iterates over the `Enumerator` passing in each language and its index along with the `a` object. It then uses the index from `b` to find the proper index in `a` and adds a language key to the hash that is equal to the language.

Please know this is a destructive method where the objects in `a` will mutate during the process. You could make it non destructive using `with_object(a.map(&:dup))` this will `dup` the hashes in a and the originals will remain untouched.

All that being said I think `YAML` would be better suited for a task like this but I am not sure what your constraints are. As an example:

```
yml = <<YML
-
  one: 1
  two: 2
  language: "english"
-
  uno: 1
  dos: 2
  language: "spanish"
YML
require 'yaml'
YAML.load(yml)
#=>[
     {"one"=>1, "two"=>2, "language"=>"english"}, 
     {"uno"=>1, "dos"=>2, "language"=>"spanish"}
    ]
```

Although using `YAML` I would change the structure for numbers to be more like language => Array of numbers by index e.g. `{"english" => ["zero","one","two"]}`. That way you can can access them like `["english"][0] #=> "zero"`